# How do you escape characters within a string (JSON format)

Tags: json, go, escaping

What is the idiomatic way to escape only the characters in a string require to be escaped by the  [JSON specification](https://www.json.org).

(I am not trying to marshal/unmarshal an object or string, I just want to escape the characters inside a string.

This works, but surely there is a more idiomatic way? https://play.golang.org/p/rcHZbrjFyyH

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(jsonEscape(`dog "fish" cat`))
    //output: dog \"fish\" cat
}

func jsonEscape(i string) string {
    b, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Trim the beginning and trailing " character
    return string(b[1:len(b)-1])
}
```

Comment: A slight improvement is to return `string(b[1:len(b)-1])`.  This reduces memory allocated by two bytes.  Otherwise, marshaling is the way to encoded form of a string (or any other value).

Comment: try HTMLEscape maybe? https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#HTMLEscape

Comment: You can simply copy what is used inside the json package to do the job. https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L876 It's around line 876. If you discount for unicodes, it's basically just a `switch`.

Comment: The json.HTMLEscape escapes additional characters with the purpose of making JSON safe for embedding into HTML. JSON only needs ", backslash, and control characters escaped.

https://www.json.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if using backticks `` ` `` is the most idiomatic way to escape characters but is more readable, for example, you could use something like:

```
fmt.Println(jsonEscape(`dog "fish" cat`))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/khG7qBROaIx

Check the [String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) section.